# Sum of continuous functions is continuous with multiple variables

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, functions, continuity

**Background**

I have seen proofs showing that the sums of two continuous functions $f_1, g_1 :$ $\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R} $ are continuous, and I have also seen this result for functions $f_2, g_2 :$ $\mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$.

However, I have not seen a generalisation of the claim for when we take the functions $f_3 : \mathbb{R}^k \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ and $g_3 : \mathbb{R}^q \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n $. If both of these functions are continuous, then this should imply that the sum is also continuous, however, I am struggling to prove the claim.

For clarity, we define the sum to be the function $h(x,y) := f_3(x) + g_3(y)$, where we want to prove that this is continuous given that $f_3, g_3$ are continuous.

**Attempt**

I have shown that the projections of $ \mathbb{R}^k $ and $ \mathbb{R}^q $

$p_1(x,y) := x \space \space$ and $\space \space p_2(x,y) := y$

are both continuous. But am unsure of how to proceed from here.

My initial thoughts are that an epsilon - delta argument should be able to work for two specified values of delta which are valid for showing that the individual functions are continuous (by our assumption).

I’m assuming we can then use these to construct a new values of delta that will hold for the sum.

However, I haven’t made much progress here as of yet.

If anyone could help me construct a proof, or point me towards a reference, I would be grateful.

Comment: What does the sum even mean in that case?

Comment: The function $h(x,y) := f_3(x) + g_3(y)$ is continuous given that the functions $f_3, g_3$ are continuous @Randall

Comment: So the new domain will be $\mathbb{R}^k \times \mathbb{R}^q$?  In that case, it follows since addition in $\mathbb{R}^n$ is continuous.

Comment: I suppose that simplifies my question down to proving that addition in $\mathbb{R}^n$ is continuous. Which I assume we can show using the sequential criterion?

Comment: Could we not show this using an epsilon delta argument? Using the assumption that there exists some $ \delta _g$ and some $\delta _f$ so that these functions are individually continuous @Randall

Comment: Sure, as long as you then decide what $\delta$ works in $\Bbb R^k\times\Bbb R^q$. I assume you're using $\epsilon/2$ to get each of those $\delta$s.

Comment: That's the argument I'm trying to construct, but haven't had much success with it @TedShifrin

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**SKETCH**: You want to prove that $h$ is continuous at $(x_0,y_0)\in\Bbb R^k\times\Bbb R^q$. Given $\epsilon>0$, there are $\delta_1,\delta_2>0$ so that
$$|x-x_0|<\delta_1 \implies |f_3(x)-f_3(x_0)|<\epsilon/2 \quad\text{and}\quad|y-y_0|<\delta_2 \implies |g_3(y)-g_3(y_0)|<\epsilon/2.$$
Let $\delta = \min(\delta_1,\delta_2)$. Now show that
$$|(x,y)-(x_0,y_0)|<\delta \implies |h(x,y)-h(x_0,y_0)|<\epsilon.$$
Note that $|h(x,y)-h(x_0,y_0)| \le |f_3(x)-f_3(x_0)|+|g_3(y)-g_3(y_0)|$.

Comment: Could you also take $\delta := | (\delta_1 , \delta_2)|$?

Comment: No. That won't work. You need to be able to conclude from $|(x,y)-(x_0,y_0)|<\delta$ that both $|x-x_0|<\delta_1$ and $|y-y_0|<\delta_2$. You'd better double-check your argument carefully! Oh, maybe I should ask: What norm are you using on $\Bbb R^k\times\Bbb R^q$? There are various options here.

Answer (score 3):

It suffices to show that if $V$ is a normed vector space over $\mathbb{R}$, then $+ : V \times V \to V$ is continuous. Here $V \times V$ is a normed space with norm $|(x, y)| = |x| + |y|$. This proof is easy using $\delta$-$\epsilon$